# ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("12:00:00") Exception

Tags: java, jodatime, periodformatter

I try to call the `parsePeriod()` with the parameter "12:00:00", and it runs an IllegalArgumentException.
I try the decompile the `PeriodFormatter` class, and `getParser().parseInto(localMutablePeriod, paramString, 0, iLocale);` this line turns wrong.
Can anybody tells me the reason? Thanks.

Comment: `ISOPeriodFormat.alternateExtended().parsePeriod("P0000-00-00T12:00:00")` would work but not `ISOPeriodFormat.alternateExtended().parsePeriod("PT12:00:00")`. (tested with Joda-Time 2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"12:00:00" is not the correct ISO 8601 duration format. See the description of the format here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

In your case, if you mean a 12-hour duration, the parameter should be "PT12H0M0S":
`ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("PT12H0M0S")`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the input to adapt it to the capabilities of the library in use is often not an option. Note that your input is not ISO-compatible because it lacks at least the prefix PT (in alternative ISO-8601-notation). Therefore I suggest following way:

```
PeriodFormatter pf =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .appendHours().appendLiteral(":")
  .appendMinutes().appendLiteral(":")
  .appendSeconds().toFormatter();
System.out.println(pf.parsePeriod("12:00:00")); // PT12H
```

Alternatively I had tested this code:

```
ISOPeriodFormat.alternateExtended().parsePeriod("P0000-00-00T12:00:00");
```

This works so far and just requires prefixing the input with the disadvantage that you have to change the input. The shorter prefix PT is ISO-compatible, too, but not supported by Joda-Time (tested in version 2.1).